# Formula to SUM cells to the left?

Tags: google-sheets, offset, google-sheets-formula

I need a Sheets formula for a Year to Date field. Essentially, I need to sum up the cells to the left of a given cell, up and to the 11 previous cells (there are multiple years in a single row). In Excel, this is accomplished via OFFSET and a -Width value. Sheets won't play nice with -Width.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

For what it's worth, the formula that doesn't work in Sheets (but does in Excel) is as follows:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(Forecast!$B$12,ROW($A13)-ROW($A$12),MATCH(Report!$I$1,Months,0)+2,1,-$I$2))
```

Where -$I$2 is a variable number of months field.

Answer (score 0):

I used indirect and the RC format. This secret sauce is the `max(COLUMN()-11,1)`.

```
=sum(INDIRECT("R"&row()&"C"&max(COLUMN()-11,1)&":R"&row()&"C"&(COLUMN()-1), FALSE))
```

or with your `$I$2` cell

```
=sum(INDIRECT("R"&row()&"C"&max($I$2-11,1)&":R"&row()&"C"&($I$2-1), FALSE))
```

Edit:

With the additional info, assuming your entry is in `br`, your first month is in `bc`, the sheet your interested in is `sh` and you want to go back `$I$2-1` columns (because `bc` counts as one)

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("sh!"&"R"&br&"C"&(bc+1-$I$2)&":R"&br&"C"&bc,false))
```

Comment: That's the closest I've gotten to an answer, but I'm not sure I quite follow. There's also a chance I may have not given a proper set up.

This formula is on Sheet 5 addressing a field on Sheet 2. Cell I2 ($I$2) is on Sheet 5 and simply numbers a selected month. I then use that cell to define how far back my SUM equation should look on Sheet 2 from a given cell in order to accurately give me a "Year to Date" number.